# replace string preceded by space

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to eliminate some unwanted text from a vector of strings in `R`, but haven't been able to achieve my desired output.

I want to eliminate any occurrences of a word, which could come in any of several variations. Take as example:

```
a<-c("xyz (ALTERNA)","jqk(ALTERNA)","abc(ALTERNO)","def ( ALTERNO)","mno (ALTERNO )","pqr (ALTERNA) ")
```

I want to eliminate any occurrence of the word `altern[ao]` with the parenthesis and any preceding space, so I tried:

```
gsub(pattern = "[:blank:]*\\(altern[ao]\\)",replacement = "",a,ignore.case = T)
```

but it produces:

```
[1] "xyz "           "jq"             "abc"            "def ( ALTERNO)" "mno (ALTERNO )" "pqr  "
```

My desired output would be:

```
[1] "xyz"     "jqK"     "abc"     "def"     "mno"     "pqr"
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `sub`.  We match zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by a parentheses (`\\(`), followed by one or more characters (`.*`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace with `''`.

```
sub('\\s*\\(.*$', '', a)
#[1] "xyz" "jqk" "abc" "def" "mno" "pqr"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I was too focused on `alterno|a` and missed the whole structure of the string... you put me back into simplicity. I noticed `gsub` works as well, is there any reason I should use one or the other?

Comment: @PavoDive There is no need for `gsub` as `sub` works well.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to wrap your POSIX class inside a bracketed expression. To fully match all those substrings you would need to modify your regular expression to account for all whitespaces.

```
[[:blank:]]*\\([[:blank:]]*altern[ao][[:blank:]]*\\)[[:blank:]]*
```

IMO, since `[:blank:]` matches space and tab without locale changes I would write this as follows if you wanted to actually match the entire substring and preceding/following whitespaces.

```
[ \\t]*\\([ \\t]*altern[ao][ \\t]*\\)[ \\t]*
```

But, for your **given** input, I would simply do:

```
gsub('[^a-z]+', '', a)
# [1] "xyz" "jqk" "abc" "def" "mno" "pqr"
```